# Vue - Access child component default props after mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out what the default properties (`props`) *were* for a child component. In this example, I have two components `A` and `B`. `B` wraps around `A` and `A` is passed properties. I'd like to figure out what the *default values* were for the component `A` from the component `B` which wraps around it, most importantly the types specified for the defaults. To be clear, in the `mounted` function of `B` I'd like to be able to see the default values and types of `A` assuming `B` will always have exactly 1 child component.

I've tried getting the child component using `this.$children[0]._props` in the `mounted` lifecycle hook, but those properties are the ones set. I've tried getting the properties earlier in the [Vue lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) (like `created`, `beforeCreate`, `beforeMount` etc.) except they don't seem to exist until mounting. I've also inspected the `this.$children[0]` object using the browser console, and haven't found any default values for the props (only getter functions which retrieve the override defaults). I'm willing to pass extra data to `B` in order to get the default properties, but would prefer not to (since it seems redundant, i.e. I should know what the component "origin" was by looking at the `this.$children[0]` object).

Minimal example is located here: https://codepen.io/maxschommer/pen/wvaqGjx
I've included the HTML and JS below for quick reference.

JS:

```
Vue.component('A', {
  name: "A",
  props: {
        prop1: {
            type: String,
            default: "The First Default Value"
        },
        prop2: {
            type: String,
            default: 'The Second Default Value'
        }
    },
  template: `<div class="A">
<h1>A Prop 1: {{ prop1 }} </h1>
<h1>A Prop 2: {{ prop2 }} </h1>
</div>`
});



Vue.component('B', {
    name: "B",
    mounted: function() {
        this.$children[0];
        // I'd like to find some way to get the default properties
        // of the child of this component (A) here (or in computed, etc.). Instead
        // this gives the values which were set. 
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.$children[0]._props));
    },
    template: 
     `<div><slot></slot></div>`});


var parent = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: 
  `<div class=templateField>
        <B>
            <A prop1="Overriding" prop2="Defaults"></A>
        </B>
        
</div>`
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
</div>
```

PS: I'm a bit confused about the difference between components and elements when refering to Vue (I believe components are JS objects and elements are when they are rendered to html) so please correct my terminology if I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: Is this more a theoretical question? It seems an odd requirement to know what the default value of a prop was before it gets overridden.

Comment: I'm trying to make a wrapper component which can detect all of the types and defaults for inputs for a component, so that a configuration GUI can be made for any component by wrapping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the original options object (the object you give Vue to construct component instances) from `this.$options`, so

```js
mounted() {
  const propDfns = this.$options.__proto__.props
  const propTypes = Object.values(propDfns).map(p => p.type.name) 
  console.log(propTypes)
},
```

Comment: Actually, it might be simpler in `created()`.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know this existed. TIL

Comment: This worked perfectly from the child component, awesome!

Comment: That's the really good thing about Vue, you just have to fish about a bit in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Components are not only JS objects. they are mixture of js, html or template and css

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm a bit new to SO, is it best practice for me to edit my question with corrected notions of components?